# Parsing nested JSON into DataFrame using json_normalize

Tags: python, json

I'm having trouble bringing data in JSON format into a DataFrame.

The output I'm looking for looks something like this:

```
Date         Arrival - Thousands (TF)    Tourism expenditure in the country - US$ Mn (IMF)
2017-12-31   76941                       251361
2016-12-31   76407                       246172
```

I tried using json_normalize in my approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

response = requests.get("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/UTOR/TOR_USA.json?api_key=5aMivNdsRkZNB-afkjse")

data = json.dumps(response.json(), sort_keys=True, indent=4)
print(data)
json_response = response.json()

df = pd.json_normalize(json_response)
df

df = df[['dataset.column_names', 'dataset.data']]
df.rename(columns = {'dataset.column_names': 'column_names', 'dataset.data': 'data'}, inplace = True)

# From here I'm not sure where to go, so I just split everything into rows and maybe I could then split the data column into two columns with one of them containing the data. But this seems very inefficient and i was hoping there'd be a better way.

df = df.explode("data")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    goal = []
    r = requests.get(url).json()
    for item in r['dataset']['data']:
        goal.append(item[:3])
    df = pd.DataFrame(goal, columns=[
                      "Date", "Arrival - Thousands (TF)", "Tourism expenditure in the country - US$ Mn (IMF)"])
    print(df)


main("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/UTOR/TOR_USA.json?api_key=5aMivNdsRkZNB-afkjse")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect thanks. I have just changed print(df) to return df.